# HTTP request fails without error in loop

Tags: node.js, http

I am trying to send HTTP request on computation of some hash, inside a loop, but the requests are failing without any error. I tried to run the code outside of loop, and it ran!

```
for(var i=startFrom;i<startFrom+blockSize;i++){
      var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(username+i).digest('hex');
      if(hash.indexOf(kZeros)==0){
        var hashRespOptions = {
          host: ipAddr,
          agent: false,
          port: hashResponsePort,
          path: '/?shaString='+i+'&shaHash='+hash
        };
        http.request(hashRespOptions,function(){}).end();
        console.log(hashRespOptions);
      }
      requestWork();
    }
```

Comment: how do you know it was failing? or What do you mean by failing?

Comment: `http.request` is an asynchronous task, you know that, right? So if you need those responses in `requestWork` - it won't work. I too don't understand what `the requests are failing` means - provide more info on that.